Export data as excel - last column shows unknown identifier 'item'
I am using Datatable.js and ClosedXML to export grid data to excel.
This is the template snapshot, column name changed for privacy -

And when I download the excel sheet, I get error in the last column, as shown -

If I change the  Reported By parameter to any other parameters ,like ABC6 or ABC7 .etc, the error stays the same. But the values are coming for all the records in the other columns. Code for exporting data as xml on server side  -
 string webRootPath = _env.WebRootPath;
 var template = new XLTemplate($"{webRootPath}\\ReportTemplates\\{model.ReportId.ToString()}Template.xlsx");
 template.AddVariable("ReportDisplayName", model.ReportDisplayName);
 template.AddVariable("ReportParameters", model);

 switch (model.ReportId)
 {
     case ReportNames.FallReport:
         var fallReportData = returnModel.ReportData as List<FallReportViewModel>;
         template.AddVariable("ReportData", fallReportData);
         break;
     ...
 } // end of switch

 template.Generate();


 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     template.SaveAs(stream);
     var fileName = $"{model.ReportDisplayName}_{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}.xlsx";
    
     return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
 }

The viewmodel has all the column datataypes defined, including Reported By column,which is defined as a string. Code for jquery side -
 buttons: [
     {
         text: 'Export to PDF',

         action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
             ....
         }
     },
     {
         text: 'Export to Excel',
         action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
             if (ValidateReportParameterAndContent()) {
                 $("#ReportType").val("xls");
                 $("#ReportDisplayName").val($("#reportName").val());
                 $("#frmReport").submit();

                 setTimeout(function () { $(".page-loader").css('display', 'none'); }, 3000);
             }
         }
     }
 ],

Code for repository file, where we fetch from database -
var myList = _context.MyReports.Include(r => r.PatientDemographic)
                .Where(r => r.CreatedDate.Date >= model.reportParameters.StartDate.Value
                && r.CreatedDate.Date <= model.reportParameters.EndDate.Value
                && !r.IsDeleted)
                .OrderBy(sortBy)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .Select(a => new FallReportViewModel
                {
                    ABC = a.PatientDemographic.ABC,
                    PatientName = a.PatientDemographic.DisplayName,
                    ReportedBy = "",
                    ABC2 = 
 a.DateOfFall.Value.Date.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy"),
                   ABC3 = a.ABC3.Value.Date.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy"),
                    CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
                    CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate.Date,
                    UpdatedDate = a.UpdatedDate,
                    ABC5 = a.ABC5,
                    ABC4 = a.ABC4,
                    ABC2 = a.ABC2,
                    ABC7 = a.ABC7.Name,
                }).ToList();


foreach (var item in myList)
{
    var reportedByUser = agencyUsers.FirstOrDefault(au => au.ApplicationUserId == item.CreatedBy);
    if (reportedByUser != null)
    {
        item.ReportedBy = $"{reportedByUser.UserName} ({reportedByUser.UserType.UserTypeName})";
    }
}


There is no code shown for neither item nor item.ReportedBy.

added the code where we fetch data from db

What is the link between template.Generate() and myList?

there is no relation. myList is returned when datagrid is loaded on the page. template.Generate() is inbuild method of ClosedXML.Report to generate excel data based on template and other details provided

Based on the behavior it is more a format issue than data issue. 1. Is the format of datagrid of column J correct? 2. What is the debug log of file streams. You could modify the model for less properties to verify if it is the length limit issue.
